# uncurry and curry functions

Tags: currying, lambda-calculus

I´m quite new to lambda-calculus and I´m trying to do the following exercise, but I´m not able to resolve it.

`uncurry(curry E) = E`

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the following definions (you need to check if those match you definitions)

```
// creates a pair of two values
pair    := λx.λy.λf. fxy
// selects the first element of the pair     
first   := λp. p(λx.λy. x)
// selects the second element of the pair                     
second  := λp. p(λx.λy. y)
// currys f
curry   := λf.λx.λy . f (pair x y)
// uncurrys f
uncurry := λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)
```

you show

```
uncurry(curry E) = E
```

by inserting the definitions above into **curry** and **uncurry** in

```
uncurry(curry E)
```

which leads to

```
(λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( (λf.λx.λy . f (pair x y)) E)
```

Then you reduce the term above using the reduction rules of the lambda-caluclus, namely using:

- α-conversion: changing bound variables
- β-reduction: applying functions to their arguments

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus
>   http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/papers/lambdanotes.pdf

which should lead to

```
E
```

if you write down each reduction step, you have proven that

```
uncurry(curry E) = E
```

here a sketch how it should look like:

```
uncurry(curry E) = // by curry-, uncurry-definion
(λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( (λf.λx.λy . f (pair x y)) E) = // by pair-definiton
(λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( (λf.λx.λy . f (λx.λy.λf. fxy x y)) E) = // 2 alpha-conversions
(λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( (λf.λx.λy . f (λa.λb.λf. fab x y)) E) = // 2 beta-reductions
(λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( (λf.λx.λy . f (λf. fxy)) E) = // ...

...
...
... = // β-reduction
E
```

Comment: the definitions match but I think that I´m failing on some reduction step. could you write down all the steps? thank you!

Comment: I think that's the point of the exercise.

Comment: Is it well that way?

uncurry (curry E) = 
λf.λp . f (first p) (second p) ( λf.λx.λy . f (pair xy) E) = 
λf.λp . f (first p) (second p) ( λx.λy.E (pair xy) ) = 
λf.λp . f (first p) (second p) E = 
λp . E (first p) (second p) = 
E

Comment: first of all: I had some bracket misses around the 'functions', I added them. They were the reasons of your odd reductions. theirfore: uncurry (curry E) = (λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( λf.λx.λy . f (pair xy) E) = (λf.λp . f (first p) (second p)) ( λx.λy.E (pair xy) ) = λp . ( λx.λy.E (pair xy) ) (first p) (second p) = λp . E (pair (first p) (second p) ) = **then insert the definition of pair, first and second and the rest should cancel

Comment: I think I´m doing it the wrong way
λp . E (λxyf . fxy ((λo . oT) p) ((λo . oF) p) ) =
λp . E (λxyf . fxy ((λo . o(λx.λy . x)) p) ((λo . o(λx.λy . y)) p) ) =
λp . E (λxyf . fxy (p (λx.λy . x)) (p (λx.λy . y))) =
λp . E (λf . f(p (λx.λy . x))(p (λx.λy . y))) =
λp . E (λf . fpp)

and now what?

Comment: if you not get the result directly show that: λp . pair (first p) (second p) == (λp.p) == id for a proper p. Than you get λp . E (pair (first p) (second p) ) = E id = E